# How to specify the type of irrational numbers in Julia?

Tags: generics, julia

This was a surprise:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.1.1 (2019-05-16)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> typeof((Base.MathConstants).e)
Irrational{:ℯ}

julia> typeof((Base.MathConstants).e) == Irrational{:e}
false
```

How do I write the type `Irrational{:e}` in Julia 1.1.1?

This expression returned true in Julia 0.5, but only because `e` was a top-level identifier. Something changed in the language between 0.5 and now. I found that `e` was moved to `Base.MathConstants`, but I have not figured out how to write its type. The REPL says one thing, but what it says cannot be used in a `==` expression.

Answer (score 4):

Note carefully that the response from

```
typeof((Base.MathConstants).e)
```

is

```
Irrational{:ℯ}
```

with an "italicized" `e`. If you copy-paste the response into the expression

```
typeof((Base.MathConstants).e) == Irrational{:ℯ}
```

and evaluate it, you will get the value

```
true
```

Here's the reason. In old versions of Julia, the constant `e` was used for the famous number 2.718281828... but apparently people liked using `e` for exceptions, so `e` was moved to `Base.MathConstants`.

However a new constant was introduced into `Base`, namely `ℯ`. This is [character U+212F](https://www.charbase.com/212f-unicode-script-small-e), a "script small e."

You can use this identifier directly in your Julia code.

Comment: If you are using the REPL, or any editor with latex/unicode completion, you can write `\euler<TAB>` to get `ℯ`.